# node wont update angular

Tags: node.js, angular

I have been struggling for days to try and get angular to update. I have finally narrowed it down to the fact when I run

```
     ng new
```

it creates an angular app using version 1.7.4 but I have updated angular to version 8.1.2. when I run

```
    ng --version
```

I get the message "your global version is 8.1.2 is greater than your local version 1.7.4 the local version will be uses"

I have run npm

```
   npm update -g@angular/cli
   npm update @angular/cli
```

but nothing. I have also deleted the files in

```
 c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular
```

and tried running

```
 npm install @angular/cli
```

Has anyone got any idea either how to update my local install of angular or when I run

```
ng new
```

to get it to use the global version?

Thanks

Comment: try clearing npm cache and run the update again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm update` will update your package to the latest **safe** version, i.e. it won't increase a major version of your current package which is `1` in your case. A change of a major version means there will be breaking changes.

So you need to explicitly specify the package version to which you want to migrate. I.e. `npm update @angular/cli@^8.1.2` or `npm install @angular/cli@^8.1.2`, sorry I mostly use `yarn` so not sure which of these 2 commands will work.